# Why unbounded operators require a restricted domain?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Usually, unbounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ are defined as linear operators from a subset of $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$. My question is why is it necessary to restrict the domain.

Suppose I have a (densely defined, if you want) linear operator $T: D(T) \subseteq \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ such that

$$ \| T \| := \sup \big\{  \| Tx\| : \, \| x \| \leq 1 , \, x \in D(T) \big\} = \infty \, . $$

Can you show that $\exists x\in \mathcal{H}$ such that $Tx \notin \mathcal{H}$, justifying the need to restrict the domain?

Comment: There is a theorem that a linear operator that has full domain must be bounded. I think it's a closed graph theorem argument? It's been a bit.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the closed graph theorem says that a linear operator with full domain is bounded iff it is closed. I don’t see why it’s not possible to have a linear operator with full domain but not bounded (and thus not closed).

Comment: Oh yep, I keep forgetting that assumption because pretty much every major theorem in unbounded operators assumes closedness. Non closed/non closable operators are kind of monstrous.

Comment: You can define an unbounded operator with full domain, that's a typical exercise in axiom of choice. In a logical system without the axiom of choice, all operators are bounded (there is a paper around with exactly this title, but I forgot the name of the authors).

Comment: The reason that it is useful is surely that useful unbounded operators exist. The unbounded derivative operator cannot be defined on all of $L^2$, $ \exists x\in L^2$ on which the derivative cannot be defined, it is not a matter of the range of this operator.

Comment: You assumed $T : \mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$. It does not make sense to say that $Tx \notin\mathcal{H}$ for some $x\in\mathcal{H}$. By your definition of $T$, it maps $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$. Assuming $Tx\notin\mathcal{H}$ contradicts the definition of $T$.